# Mostrar modal al iniciar sesión con javaScript

Tags: php, javascript, login, modal

Estoy haciendo un panel de administración con su inicio de sesión. Lo tengo bastante avanzado ya, pero quiero que cuando inicien sesión me cargue un modal que tengo preparado que es como una especie de saludo de bienvenida y se cierra solo pasados 3s por ejemplo. Pero la verdad no se muy bien como hacerlo, voy a mostrar lo que tengo hasta ahora.

`login.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
 if ($_POST['user']) {
 if ($_POST['user'] == "info@artdesigns.es" && $_POST['pass'] == "123") 
 {
 $_SESSION['autorizado'] = TRUE;

 $cookie_name = "alert";
 $cookie_value = "true";
 setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (200000), "/");

// Asigno el momento (hora actual) en el que se inicia sesión.

$_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
header ("location: index.php");

} else {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
  , 'check();'
  , '</script>'
  ;
 }
 }
```

`validaLogin.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['autorizado'],$_SESSION['tiempo'])){
header("location: /_admin/login.php");
exit;
}
/*
* Se establece la duración de una sesión por 20 minutos.
* 20 minutos = 1200 segundos.
* La hora de finalización de la sesión se actualiza cuando el usuario realiza una nueva acción en el servidor.
*
*/
// Hora actual
$time = time();
// Si la sesión está activa y ha pasado más de 1200 segundos desde su 
ultima acción en el servidor,
// se cierra la sesión actual, se redirecciona a login.php.
if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo']) && ($time - $_SESSION['tiempo']) >= 1200 ){
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
exit;
}
// Si la validación anterior no tiene efecto, la hora de la ultima acción se actualiza.
if(isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])){
$_SESSION['tiempo'] = $time;
}
?>
```

`index.php`

Ya se que lo que voy a poner no vale, pero es para que veais lo que quiero hacer.

**Esto es lo que tenia yo**

```
<?php require('validaLogin.php');?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#mensaje').modal('show');

      setTimeout(function(){
      $('#mensaje').modal('hide');
        },1550);
  </script>
```

**Esto es lo que he puesto tuyo**

```
  <script>        
      // Comprobamos si existe la cookie
      var result = document.getElementById("result");
      if(readCookie("alert")=="true") {
          result.innerHTML = "Cookie="+readCookie("alert")+". En este caso se mostraría una ventana modal";
          // Borramos la cookie
          eraseCookie("alert");
      }
      else {
          result.innerHTML = "Cookie="+readCookie("alert")+". En este caso NO se mostraría una ventana modal";
      }
  </script>

  <script>
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else {
            var expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
     }
  </script>
```

Supongo que seria hacer algo en plan, si validaLogin esta OK carga este mensaje, pero claro solo quiero que salga una vez que inicia sesión, no cada vez que carga el index.php
Otra cosa que me sucede es que el `script` me toca ponerlo abajo del todo por que si no, no funciona. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que un usuario inicia sesión y muestras el mensaje, deberías de colocar una cookie. El mensaje sólo debería de mostrarse si no existe la cookie. Al iniciar sesión debes de comprobar si existe está cookie y borrarla.

Ejemplo:

1.- Al hacer login, creamos una cookie para indicar esta situación

```
<?php        
    // Si el login es satisfactorio, creamos una cookie
    $cookie_name = "alert";
    $cookie_value = "true";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (200000), "/"); 
?>
```

2.- En la vista mostramos la ventana modal si existe esta cookie. Tras mostrarla, borramos la cookie.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
    <script>        
        // Comprobamos si existe la cookie
        var result = document.getElementById("result");
        if(readCookie("alert")=="true") {
            result.innerHTML = "Cookie="+readCookie("alert")+". En este caso se mostraría una ventana modal";
            // Borramos la cookie
            eraseCookie("alert");
        }
        else {
            result.innerHTML = "Cookie="+readCookie("alert")+". En este caso NO se mostraría una ventana modal";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

3.- En el punto 2, he usado unos métodos para trabajar con cookies, que he obtenido de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7215572/2144342):

```
<script>
        function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000));
                var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            else {
                var expires = "";
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        function eraseCookie(name) {
            createCookie(name,"",-1);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Sabes de algún tutorial por ahi para hacerme una idea?

Comment: Si me da tiempo esta mañana, amplio la respuesta con un ejemplo

Comment: perdona @Alejandro Nortes, no me llego el aviso de tu respuesta.  He estado mirando lo que me mandas, pero no se muy bien como maquetarlo en mi código. voy a modificar mi mensaje original para que veas como lo he realizado, muchas gracias

Comment: También decirte que lo estoy trabajando en el local, siendo así guarda las cookies también?